# How to custom sort pandas multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas

The following code generates the pandas table named `out`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Book': ['B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B3', 'B3'], 
                   'Trader': ['T1', 'Z2', 'Z2', 'T1', 'U3', 'T2'], 
                   'Position':[10, 33, -34, 87, 43, 99]})
df = df[['Book', 'Trader', 'Position']]

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Book', 'Trader'], values=['Position'], aggfunc=np.sum)

print(table)

tab_tots = table.groupby(level='Book').sum()
tab_tots.index = [tab_tots.index, ['Total'] * len(tab_tots)]
print(tab_tots)

out = pd.concat(
    [table, tab_tots]
).sort_index().append(
    table.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total'))
)
```

The table `out` look like [image: this.]

But I would like it to look like [image: this.]

Notice how the second table always puts the 'Total' at the bottom. So basically I still want to sort alphabetically but I would like to always put 'Total' last. Could someone provide an adjustment to my code that gives my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape. Then easy add new `Total` column, count `Grand Total` and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Last add new row by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Book','Trader']).Position.sum().unstack()
df1['Total'] = df1.sum(1)
all_sum = df1['Total'].sum()
df1 = df1.stack()
df1.loc[('Grand','Total')] = all_sum
df1 = df1.reset_index(name='Position')
print (df1)
    Book Trader  Position
0     B1     T1      10.0
1     B1     Z2      33.0
2     B1  Total      43.0
3     B2     Z2     -34.0
4     B2  Total     -34.0
5     B3     T1      87.0
6     B3     T2      99.0
7     B3     U3      43.0
8     B3  Total     229.0
9  Grand  Total     238.0
```

Comparing with another solution:

```
def jez(df):
    df1 = df.groupby(['Book','Trader']).Position.sum().unstack()
    df1['Total'] = df1.sum(1)
    all_sum = df1['Total'].sum()
    df1 = df1.stack()
    df1.loc[('Grand','Total')] = all_sum
    df1 = df1.reset_index(name='Position')
    return (df1)


def ted1(df):
    table = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                           index=['Book'], 
                           columns=['Trader'], 
                           values=['Position'], 
                           aggfunc=np.sum, 
                           margins=True, 
                           margins_name='total')
    return table.stack()\
                  .rename({'total':'Total'})\
                  .reset_index(1)\
                  .rename({'Total':'Grand'})\
                  .reset_index()\
                  .query('Book != "Grand" | Trader == "Total"')


print (jez(df))
print (ted1(df))

In [419]: %timeit (jez(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.65 ms per loop

In [420]: %timeit (ted1(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 26.5 ms per loop
```

Conclusion:

For subtotals is faster `groupby+unstack` solution, also easier `sum` of subtotals.

`pivot_table` for pivoting easier (one function), but more complicated for manipulation with subtotal + total rows.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has built-in functionality within the `pivot_table` function to compute the marginal totals.

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, 
               index='Book', 
               columns='Trader', 
               values='Position', 
               aggfunc=np.sum, 
               margins=True, 
               margins_name='Total').drop('Total').stack()
table[('Grand', 'Total')] = table.sum()
table.name = 'Position'
table.reset_index()

     Book Trader  Position
0      B1     T1      10.0
1      B1     Z2      33.0
2      B1  Total      43.0
3      B2     Z2     -34.0
4      B2  Total     -34.0
5      B3     T1      87.0
6      B3     T2      99.0
7      B3     U3      43.0
8      B3  Total     229.0
13  Grand  Total     238.0
```

### Solution based on sorting multi-index

This solution continues off from your analysis by starting from your `out` DataFrame. You can convert `Book` and `Trader` to Pandas categorical type which allows you to custom sort by passing in the argument `ordered=True` and a list of the `categories` in the order you want sorted.

```
out = out.reset_index()

trader_cats = pd.Categorical(out['Trader'], 
                   categories=sorted(df.Trader.unique()) + ['Total'], 
                   ordered=True)

book_cats = pd.Categorical(out['Book'], 
                   categories=sorted(df.Book.unique()) + ['Grand'], 
                   ordered=True)

out['Trader'] = trader_cats
out['Book'] = book_cats
out.set_index(['Book', 'Trader'], inplace=True)
out.sort_index(level=['Book', 'Trader'])

              Position
Book  Trader          
B1    T1            10
      Z2            33
      Total         43
B2    Z2           -34
      Total        -34
B3    T1            87
      T2            99
      U3            43
      Total        229
Grand Total        238
```